# Get the order object in Woocommerce email-header template

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am trying to fetch order items in WooCommerce email header for some conditional content in `emails/email-header.php` Woocommerce template file

I have tried to `print_r` the `$order` but it's empty and not giving any results.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way to get the `**$order**` object, is to include the **`$email`** global variable back in the template (as it should be, like in the related hooked function):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', 'email_header_before', 1, 2 );
function email_header_before( $email_heading, $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email'] = $email;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

Once **done** and **saved**, in your template emails/email-header.php you will insert the following at the beginning:

```
<?php
    // Call the global WC_Email object
    global $email; 

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = $email->object; 
?>
```

So know you can use the WC_Order object `$order` anywhere on the template like:

```
<?php echo __('City: ') . $order->get_billing_city(); // display the billing city ?>
```

or to fetch order items:

```
<?php
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
        // get the product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        // get the product (an instance of the WC_Product object)
        $product = $item->get_product();
    } 
?>
```

Tested and works